# How do I use a webhook in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, webhooks

I've just started using Dialogflow. I'm new in it, and I don't really do that much advanced code. I tried using the prebuilt Currency Converter Agent, but then I realized I had to configure some kind of webhook (i've never heard about webhooks). How do I use it, and how would I configure the webhook to match with this prebuilt agent?

Answer (score 2):

A "webhook" is code that runs on a website, but isn't meant for people to access directly. Instead, some other program accesses it at the URL for the webhook and sends it some information, usually in a data-specific format such as JSON. Similarly, instead of returning HTML, it returns data in JSON format again for the calling program to use.

Dialogflow uses this for fulfillment - it sends the fulfillment webhook information about what the user has entered (the Intent, parameters set during it, etc) via a special JSON formatted request, and expects a specially formatted JSON response.

You can run this webhook anywhere that has a publicly accessible hostname that is running an HTTPS server. However, Dialogflow also has an [Inline Editor](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-inline-editor) which lets you write simple fulfillment without having to worry about some of the details involved in setting up a webhook.